# passing parameters to functions called by dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and implementing stack.
I am calling stack functions using dictionary.
However, push() requires me to pass a parameter.
How do I do that?

```
class stack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def getStack(self):
        return print(self.items)

s = stack()
switcher = {
           '1' : s.push,
           '2' : s.pop,
           '3' : s.isEmpty,
           '4' : s.getStack,
        }

def dictionaryCall(key):
    switcher[key]()

while(1):
    key = input('enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit: ')
    if key == '5':
        break
    dictionaryCall(key)
```

Comment: Well, where do you want the value for that parameter to come from?

Comment: I want the user to fill the stack @DanielRoseman

Comment: yes, Thankyou @PM2Ring

Comment: How do you want the user to supply the parameter for `push`? One option is to put it on the same input line as the key, so they enter `'1 42'` to push 42 onto the stack.  Or you could have an extra `input` call that gets the parameter from the next line.

Comment: Normally, a stack `pop` method returns the popped item. Your code doesn't do that. And why are you doing `return print`? The `print` function always returns `None`.

Comment: I got a  KeyError: '1 42' when I tried putting it on same line

Comment: @PM2Ring my bad again, I am sorry.

Comment: Yes, If you want to put the `push` parameter on the same input line as the key then your program needs to get the input string and split it to separate the key from the parameter. It's easier to just read the parameter from the next line. But it's more convenient for the user if they can supply the parameter on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version where the `push` parameter is supplied on the same line as the key. This makes the code a little more complicated, but it's a bit nicer to use. We use the `.strip` method to remove any leading or trailing whitespace from the input string. Then, after we check for the '5' exit key, we split the input line if its longer than 1 character. The first item on the line becomes the key, the following characters after the space become the parameter for the `push` function.

This code also checks that a key is valid before attempting to use it.

I've added [`import readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html), which gives line editing and a history buffer to the input line, so you can hit the Up arrow key to get to previous lines. At least, it does that on GNU systems, it does nothing on Windows, although there's a 3rd-party pyreadline you could use instead.

```
import readline

class Stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        # Return None if the stack is empty
        if self.items:
            return self.items.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self.items

    def getStack(self):
        return self.items

stack = Stack()
switcher = {
    '1' : stack.push,
    '2' : stack.pop,
    '3' : stack.isEmpty,
    '4' : stack.getStack,
}

def dictionaryCall(key, val=None):
    func = switcher[key]
    if val is None:
        return func()
    else:
        return func(val)

while True:
    key = input('Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > ').strip()
    if key == '5':
        break

    if len(key) > 1:
        # There's a value after the key.
        key, val = key.split(maxsplit=1)
    else:
        val = None

    if key not in switcher:
        print('Invalid choice')
        continue

    if key == '1' and val is None:
        print('You must supply an item to push')
        continue

    result = dictionaryCall(key, val)
    if result is not None:
        print(result)
```

Here's a short demo

```
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 3
True
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 4
[]
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 1
You must supply an item to push
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 1 Hello
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 1 This is a test
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 4
['Hello', 'This is a test']
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 3
False
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 2
This is a test
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 2
Hello
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 2
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 3
True
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 4
[]
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 1 bye
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 4
['bye']
Enter choice: 1.push item 2.pop 3.isEmpty 4.getStack 5.exit > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's a working implementation. As you can see you will have to add an optional second parameter (called `element` here) to `dictionaryCall` and then pass it to the selected method.

```
class stack():

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        print(self.items.pop())

    def isEmpty(self):
        # I dropped the `return` here due to syntax error
        print (self.items == [])

    def getStack(self):
        # I dropped the `return` here due to syntax error
        print (self.items)

s = stack()
switcher = {
            '1' : s.push,
            '2' : s.pop,
            '3' : s.isEmpty,
            '4' : s.getStack,
        }

# I added an optional parameter for the `push` method
def dictionaryCall(key, element = None):
    method = switcher[key]

    # call the method with element if it exists
    if element == None: method()
    else: method(element)

# call from command line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(1):
        key = input('enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit: ')
        if key == '5':
            break

        print ('> {0}'.format(key))

        if key == '1':
            element = input('enter an element to push onto the stack: ')
            dictionaryCall(key, element)
        else: dictionaryCall(key)
```

**EXAMPLE**:

```
enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit: '1'
> 1
enter an element to push onto the stack: 'foo'
enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit: '3'
> 3
False
enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit: '4'
> 4
['foo']
enter choice 1.push 2. pop 3.isEmpty 4 getStack 5.exit:
```

---

A couple of things you need to pay attention to:

- `return print (...)` is not valid syntax (just write `print (...)`)
- arguments read from the command line via `input` are evaluated (that means you have to enter e.g. `'1'` to push an element since your dictionary has string keys
- to run a python program from the command line you need to wrap it in `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` otherwise the file will be parsed but not executed
- as @Pm2Ring said in the comments, `pop` should print the popped element

Comment: `return print` is perfectly valid. It's just not very useful, since it always returns `None`. Also, reading from the command line (which can be done by accessing `sys.argv`) is not the same thing as reading from the  terminal  with `input`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Is is though? Try the following program `if __name__ == '__main__':
    return print('foo')`. I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Also, what's the difference between reading from the terminal and reading from the command line?

Comment: @Becky welcome! If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: @FK82 You can't have a `return` statement outside a function.

Comment: Command line arguments are arguments written on the command line after the script's name. The shell reads those arguments and passes them to the script when it launches the script process. Once the script is running it can read stuff from the terminal itself using `input`, or `sys.stdin.read`, etc.

Comment: @Becky Sure, `return print (..)` will print the stuff you tell it to print, and then it returns `None` to the code that called the function.

Comment: yeah, Thankyou @PM2Ring I'll remember it

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right. I meant to write `if __name__ == '__main__':
    def printFoo():
        return print('foo')

    printFoo()` which raises a syntax error. Btw, and obviously no offense, but your distinction between **command line** and **terminal** does seem a bit vauge. I honestly fail to see the difference between _reading from the command line_ and _reading from the terminal_ (except maybe that one is Windows terminology and the other one Unix).

Comment: You could only get a syntax error from that code if you tried to run it on Python 2, where `print` is a statement, not a function. Note that in Python 2.6+ you can tell the interpreter to enable the `print` function by putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your imports. But really, you should be using Python 3 unless you need to maintain old Python 2 code. Python 3 is almost 10 years old, and Python 2 reaches its official End of Life some time in 2020.

Comment: The _terminology_ regarding the terminal, console, command prompt, shell, command processor, etc, varies from one OS to another, which can make it hard to explain this stuff clearly. But the basic principle is the same across all modern operating systems. You have a terminal window with input and output streams which is connected to a shell program (aka a command processor). The shell reads a command line from the input stream. That command line consists of a program name, possibly followed by some arguments.

Comment: (cont) The shell then launches the named program, passing it the arguments in an array, and giving that program temporary control of the input & output streams. While the program is running it can read from the input stream, in Python we do that with the `input()` function. The program _cannot_ read the command line arguments from the input stream: they've already been read by the shell. When the program terminates, control of the window reverts to the shell.